# jquery mobile lineup controls in a line

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How do I lineup up form controls like select boxes and others in a line in jquery vs having them displayed vertically?

```
<label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1">
   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
<label for="select-choice-2" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```

I don't want them in the same fieldset with data-type="horizontal". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative Example using CSS and data-inline="true" tag

- http://jsfiddle.net/CFXxt/

CSS

```
#inline-select-container {
    overflow:auto;
}
#inline-select-left {
    float:left;
}

#inline-select-right {
     float:right;
}
​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <div id="inline-select-container">

            <div id="inline-select-left">    
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-inline="true">
                   <option >Shipping method</option>
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="inline-select-right">
                <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2" data-inline="true">
                   <option >Shipping method</option>
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>       

        </div>  

        <br />
        <br />

        <div id="inline-select-container">

            <div id="inline-select-left">    
                <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-inline="true">
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="inline-select-right">
                <label for="select-choice-2" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2" data-inline="true">
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>       

        </div>          
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Hi phil thanks for your anwsers. The thing is that this is on a toolbar div container, so it's not the only elements in that div, that div contains buttons and checkboxes also, it's a filter toolbar. I am going to keep trying to fight it a little bit... ill post the rest of the code latter. Thanks!

Comment: I would look at these then: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html and http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Answer (score 2):

Would a grid layout work for you? Here is a Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/RM5eq/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1">
                   <option>Shipping method</option>
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
                   <option>Shipping method</option>
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>       
        </div>

    </div>
</div>​
```

Docs for the Grid Layout options

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: The grid layout works partially there is still a lot of space, I would like to have minimum space between widgets

Answer (score 1):

I have liked [jquery-mobile-960](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/).

*jquery-mobile-960 is a port of 960 grid to jquery mobile. It merge the flexibility of 960.gs, and the ease of jquery mobile. It aims to bring more flexibility to jquery-mobile layout and thus make it easier to use on tablets.*